# Add tabulation in colum csv file

Tags: csv, sed

i need to "parse" a cvs file with sth like 400 000 lines.
The cvs looks like :

```
ADDRESS ZIPCODE TOWN      NAME       DESCRIPTION
```

I need to separate the 1st colum like this :

```
ADDRESS     ZIPCODE     TOWN      NAME       DESCRIPTION
```

it looks easy : add tabulation (before and after) ZIPCODE  everytime i see 5 digits (all address are french Zip code).

But i don't know how ?
I try by a sed commande line but i can't find the good syntax. or maybe a VBA should be more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/( [0-9]{5} )/\t\1\t/' yourFile.csv
```

**Note**

- column command is good solution to your problem, if your csv is *really* well formatted. e.g. there is no "," in your description text.
- the sed line above will check each line of your file, find the first occurrence of  5 numbers/digits and wrap it with TAB. I assume that the zipcodes in your file would be `[space]number{5}[space]`
- the sed line would fail if there was same format in your "ADDRESS" column.

Comment: Perfect, all my adress are "well format", no ",".
Exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Using the column command will split out the fields of the .csv file like so:

`column -s, -t file.csv`